# How to override the back button on a "showDialog" in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to show a dialog Box when users try to logOut and I want to override the back button if the user tries to press back while the dialog box is present on screen.
For that I tried to use **WillPopScope** but somewhere I am doing things wrong. It is throwing me an error :

[image]

**Logging out code :**

```
class LogOut extends StatelessWidget {
  const LogOut({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async{
        print("pressed back button");
        return false;
      },
      child: _showLoaderDialog(context),
    );
  }

  _showLoaderDialog(BuildContext context){
    AlertDialog alert=AlertDialog(
      content: new Row(
        children: [
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
          Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7),child:Text("Logging out..." )),
        ],),
    );
    showDialog(barrierDismissible: false,
      context:context,
      builder:(BuildContext context){
        return alert;
      },
    );

  }
}
```

Why this error is showing up ? Another question which I want to ask that where can I write the logging out logic code which when completes pop the dialog box and route to login page screen ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if understand what do you want exactly, but if you want to cancel the back button effect while the dialog box  in the screen you can wrap it in WillPopScope too like this :

```
class HomePage  extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

Future<bool> exitConfirm() async {
  
  return await showDialog(
    barrierDismissible : false,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: AlertDialog(
        content:  Row(
          children: [
            CircularProgressIndicator(),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7),child:Text("Logging out..." )),
          ],),

      ),
    ),
  )??false;
}


return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop:exitConfirm,
  child: Scaffold  (

      appBar: AppBar(),
    body: const Center(
      child: Text('Test page'),
    )
  ),
);

 }

 }
```

The result:

[image]

notice that I have added this line to the showDialog so when you click on the screen the dialog doesn't dismiss :

```
barrierDismissible : false,
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I wanted. Could you also tell me where to write the log out logic and pop out the dialog box ?

Answer (score 0):

The code :

```
class HomePage  extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

Future<bool> exitConfirm() async {
  return await showDialog( 
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
      content: const Text('Do you want to exit ?'),
      actions:[
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
          child:const Text('Yes'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
          child:const Text('No'),
        ),

      ],
    ),
  )??false;
}


return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop:exitConfirm,
  child: Scaffold  (

      appBar: AppBar(),
    body: const Center(
      child: Text('Test page'),
      )
    ),
  );

 }

}
```

The result:

[image]

if you want just to cancel the back button effect you can do this :

```
onWillPop: () async => false,
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but my question was bit different, I want to show a dialog box but also override the back button, for eg. in your code if I press back button it shows a dialog box but I do not want any of these , I just want to cancel the back button effect